# Want to print consecutive 1's in

Tags: python-3.x

```
from array import *
n=int(input("Enter the number"))
m=bin(n)
#print(m)
a=array("u",[])
a=int(m[2:])
print(a)
count=0
for i in range(a):
    if(a[i]=="1" and a[i+1]=="1"):
        count=count+1
print(count)
```

Here i want to print'ONLY' the number of consecutive 1's that appear in a binary number.

Comment: Question is not clear, what do you want the output if the binary of the input is 1101111?

Comment: The line `a=array("u",[])` has no meaning whatsoever. Also I am guessing you are getting an error for `if(a[i]=="1" and a[i+1]=="1")` as `int` objects are not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is correct try this,

```
n = int(input('Enter a number : '))
nb =bin(n)
l = list(nb)[2:]
count = 0
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i]=='1' and l[i+1]=='1':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks Gayal kuruppu but can you please explain me the purpose of writing  l[i]='1' twice inside the if condition.

Comment: sorry the second one is l[i+1]=='1', this works fine

Comment: This actually messes up the logic let me make you understand this

Comment: Suppose the binary number for 5 is 101 now i want to print total number of consecutive ones in this (for 5 it is 1).Your code which was l[i] worked fine for some test cases.